# Can't install gimp-plugin-registry

Tags: 10.10, package-management, gimp

I tried to install the Ubuntu Studio Graphics meta-package, however it didn't install correctly.The package

```
  gimp-plugin-registry
```

just won`t install, i tried the one in the Software center and the one on the WebUp8 PPA neither package works.

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
gimp-plugin-registry
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0B/1395kB of archives.
After this operation, 3592kB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 402557 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking gimp-plugin-registry (from .../gimp-plugin-registry_3.2-1_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/gimp-plugin-registry_3.2-1_i386.deb (-       -unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/file-xmc', which is also in package    gimp 2.7.3-2010110501~mm
dpkg-deb: subprocess paste killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/gimp-plugin-registry_3.2-1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: We'll need a little more information about the problem. How do you know the package didn't install correctly? Was there an error message? What is the output of `sudo apt-get install gimp-plugin-registry` in a terminal?

Comment: added the error

Comment: Stable GIMP 2.8 has been released so IMO you should give it another try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've installed a conflicting gimp version from a PPA (2.7.3-2010110501~mm)

You'll need to either

- remove that PPA for your apt sources.list and install the regular gimp package instead
- find a plugin registry install that works with the version you have installed
- force the apt-get install to ignore the error (not sure how to be honest)

Comment: well im using the testing i think PPA for GIMP, too bad, ima search for a packagae that works, cause going back to GIMP 2.6 , not nice :(

Comment: Not really an answer so I don't know why it has been marked as such. I've been using testing versions of GIMP for a year now and for every sub-version it was possible to install gimp-plugin-registry so I don't believe this time we should dismiss any attempts to get it working for ubuntu 12.04 + gimp 2.8+.

Comment: Since most people I know of install gimp-plugin-registry only to get gimp save for web plugin here's how to install the single plugin http://gimper.net/viewtopic.php?f=54&t=11981&p=112896#p112896